# dsp biquad filter reset with initial values

Tags: matlab, filter, signal-processing

I'm using the dsp library and the `dsp.biquad` function to implement a butterworth IIR filter. I am setting an initial value when I create the filter as shown below:

```
function [lowpassIIR_minutes] = createLowpassIIR_minutes(initialValue)

% The following code was used to design the filter coefficients:
%
% N    = 1;         % Order
% F3dB = 8.67e-05;  % 3-dB Frequency
% Fs   = 1;         % Sampling Frequency
%
% h = fdesign.lowpass('n,f3db', N, F3dB, Fs);
%
% Hd = design(h, 'butter', ...
%     'SystemObject', true);

lowpassIIR_minutes = dsp.BiquadFilter( ...
    'Structure', 'Direct form II', ...
    'SOSMatrix', [1 1 0 1 -0.999455396157461 0], ...
    'ScaleValues', [0.00027230192126942; 1],...
    'InitialConditions', initialValue./2);
```

I want to periodically reset the filter and when I do, the initial values will be different. The biquad reset function doesn't allow me to pass an initial value so at the moment I just recreate the filter by calling the above.

However, I think this might be a bit slow. I haven't measured it, but it is called quite frequently. Can anyone suggest a way to reset the filter to an arbitrary initial value? Or is there another library that would let me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the release method for dsp.BiquadFilter and then set the InitialConditions to a different value. When you calculate output next time, the new InitialConditions value should be automatically picked up. This will incur a slight slow down compared to not calling release method. But this should be faster than recreating the object.

```
lowpassIIR_minutes = dsp.BiquadFilter( ...
    'Structure', 'Direct form II', ...
    'SOSMatrix', [1 1 0 1 -0.999455396157461 0], ...
    'ScaleValues', [0.00027230192126942; 1],...
    'InitialConditions', initialValue./2);
out = lowpassIIR_minutes(in);
release(lowpassIIR_minutes);
lowpassIIR_minutes.InitialConditions = initialValue/5;
out = lowpassIIR_minutes(in); % Uses new InitialConditions
```

Comment: Hi Navan, thanks, great answer. Calling the filter object with the input as a parameter doesn't work for me, but if I replace those with `step(lowpassIIR_minutes,value);` then it works fine. Also, did you intend to change the divider on the initial value?

Comment: Calling filter object with the input data is a newer syntax. For older versions you need to call step method. I changed the divider in initial value just to show setting of different initial value.